# PIL image.open() not working for my .png

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library, steganography

I use PIL to open image for extracting several bits and writing them to string. It supposed to be, that this code will filter except ones, that have (R<=1 && G<=1 && B<=1) and took last bit of each color. The matter is that it doesn't work.

```
from PIL import Image
def extract_bits(color, bitmask):
    bitmask_len = len(bin(bitmask)[2:])
    extracted_bits = bin(color & bitmask)[2:]
    extracted_bits = '0' * (bitmask_len - len(extracted_bits)) + extracted_bits

    return extracted_bits

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = Image.open('IMG_0707png')
    pixels = list(img.getdata())

    bits = ''
    for i in range(0, len(pixels), 1):
        r = pixels[i][0]
        g = pixels[i][1]
        b = pixels[i][2]

        if not (r <= 1 and g <= 1 and b <= 1): continue

        bits += extract_bits(r, 0x1)
        bits += extract_bits(g, 0x1)
        bits += extract_bits(b, 0x1)

    bits += '0' * (8 - len(bits) % 8)

    text = ''
    for i in range(0, len(bits), 8):
        text += chr(int(bits[i:i+8], 2))
    print text
```

I looked around this problem, and found solution that doesn't work in my case.
`img = Image.open(open('IMG_0707.png', 'rb'))`
In both cases I get

```
File "<stdin>, line 1, in <module>"
File "<string>" line11, im <module>
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1980, in open
raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Also I tried to specify exact path with no luck.

```
img = Image.open(open("IMG_0707.png", 'rb'))
img = Image.open(open("c:\python27\IMG_0707.png", 'rb'))
img = Image.open(open("c:/python27/IMG_0707.png", 'rb'))
```

And so on. I would be grateful for any help.
[Image, im trying to open](http://bit.ly/14qCm2X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That PNG is corrupted. Here is what ImageMagick had to say:

```
$ convert IMG_0707.png IMG_0707-new.png 
convert: IHDR: CRC error `IMG_0707.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1309.
convert: corrupt image `IMG_0707.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3294.
convert: missing an image filename `IMG_0707-new.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try another way solving this on CTF-challenge.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Image
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

im = Image.open(StringIO(raw_data))
```

hi i had the same problem and this is the solution
raw_data: in my case it was base64 decoded png file